# How to get user info with bot token

Tags: python, slack-api

I am using python slack client to connect and send messages with a bot application.

```
slc = SlackClient("BOT_USER_TOKEN")
out = slc.api_call(method='users.profile.get', user='XXX')
```

I am getting `not_allowed_token_type` error in output json. I am able to call:

```
slc.api_call(method='chat.PostMessage',channel)
```

Is there a way to get user email, name from slack API. previously I got the username from event messages. but now I am getting only user id so I am looking for a solution to fetch user info using that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get this error message is that [`users.profile.get`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get) does not work with bot tokens.

To mitigate just use the user token that you received along with your bot token when installing your Slack app.